# Unable to add data to mysql database using php & javascript after adding an auto_increment id column

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am creating a simple form using php, mysql and javascript. The idea is to have the user input the text, then the text is saved to the database, at the same time the latest text that the user have input returns from the database and shows on the same page without refreshing the page. The submitting function worked before I manually added the id column to the table. Please take a look of my codes and help me fix it, thank you.

submit.php ↓

```
<?php

$conn = mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die (mysql_error);
$db = mysql_select_db('qinglish_nihaoemilie') or die (mysql_error);

$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$table = 'emilieinfo_lastname';

mysql_query("INSERT INTO $table VALUES('$lastname',NULL)");

?>
```

return.php ↓

```
<?php

$conn = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
$db = mysql_select_db('qinglish_nihaoemilie');

$res = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM emilieinfo_lastname ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
$result = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
    array_push($result, array('lastname' => $row[0]));
}

echo json_encode(array('result' => $result));
?>
```

Javascript ↓

```
$('.lastname-container i').click(function(){
    var lastnameInput = $('.lastname').val();
    var lastnameInputLength = lastnameInput.length;
    if (lastnameInputLength > 0) {
        $('.lastname').hide();
        $(this).hide();
        var data = {
        lastname: $('.lastname').val(),
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../php/submitinfo-lastname.php",
            data: data,
        });

        $(this).parent().parent().find('p .fa-pencil-square-o').addClass('inline-table');
        $(this).parent().parent().find('p .fa-pencil-square-o').show();

        // $.getJSON("../php/returninfo-lastname.php", function(result){
        //  $.each(result, function(i, lastname){
        //      $(this).parent().parent().find('span').append(lastname + '');
        //  });
        // });

        // $.getJSON("../php/returninfo-lastname.php", function(returndata){
        //  $.each(returndata.result, function(){
        //      $(this).parent().parent().find('span').append("a"+this['lastname']);
        //  });
        // });
    };

    if (lastnameInputLength == 0) {
        $('.lastname').addClass('red-underline');
        $(this).addClass('red-color');
    };  
});
```

Database screenshot ↓

[image: database screenshot]

HTML ↓

```
<h2>
    <p>last name: 
        <span></span> 
        <i style="position:static; display: none;padding-left:5px;" class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>
    </p>
    <div class="lastname-container">
        <input class="lastname" name="lastname" type="text">
        <i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i>
    </div>
</h2>
```

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: I just followed an old tutorial, thank you i'll look into that.

Comment: Definitely look into that stuff - very important - but in the meantime - what if you try taking the ", NULL" out of the query (so it's just $lastname being inserted)? Your database should automatically assign the next ID so long as the field is auto-increment.

Comment: Hi Mark thanks for the reply, I removed the NULL and still can't insert data to the database, however if i deleted the id column in the database, the data can be successfully inserted.

Answer (score 0):

Should your query not look something like this

```
mysql_query('INSERT INTO '.$table.' VALUES("'.$lastname.'")');
```

Also maybe try running your query in the mySQL SQL window to make sure your query actually works

Comment: Hi Andy thanks for the reply, I tried and it still doesn't work.

Comment: This is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

check this query

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO $table (lastname,id) VALUES('$lastname',NULL)");
```

Comment: This is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Hi Bart thanks for the reply, I tried this code but it does not work, I'm thinking the problem might be from the javascript since only theres no id value posted.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_query('INSERT INTO `emilieinfo_lastname`(`lastname`) VALUES('{$lastname}'));
```

Just remove `id` and `NULL` value since it is an `AUTO_INCREMENT` field you can just remove that when you `INSERT` you data.

Comment: This is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Yes, but as i can see he's still using the classic `mysql_query` if he's in `PDO` or `mylsqi` i can use named variable as you can see i'm just been in line with his question and i don't wanna complicate the process that he is using as of now, thanks BTW for noticing @Pang i can also see that. :)

Comment: Hi Matt thanks for the reply, I tried your code unfortunately its not working, I'm thinking the problem might be from the javascript since only theres no id value posted.